# Firefox extension multiline notification

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm currently developing a firefox extension that monitores some ressource on the web and displays a notification for certain events. Currently I'm using the 'nsIAlertService' the following way:

```
var alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService);
alertsService.showAlertNotification(image , title, msg, true, "", onNotificationClicked);
```

I would like to have two things:

1) Multiline notifications (I have some detail information that I would like to display), is there a simple way to display them?

2) When the user hovers the statusbar icon a popup with some clickable links should open. I suspect that I have to write a XUL-file and manage popup and popin "by hand"...which is okay if someone has some sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (1), unless you roll your own notification system, it's not possible on all platforms.  This "just works" on the mac (if the user has Growl installed), and may work on Linux.

For (2), you'll want to take a look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Popup_Menus).